# CF - Check input and create directory (device or smart

Tags: compact-framework, directory

In my CF application i have a textbox where user defines a directory.

I want to check if the input is valid and create the directory.

The path can be either on the device itself or on a storage card.

can some1 please help me with the correct solution?

thanx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating is going to be up to you.  There is a lot to it, including scraping for invalid chanacters, etc.

Creating the directory is pretty simple.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("/MyDirectory");
```

Comment: yes thanx, i found that already. Also i did all the validation.
But ... is there a control like file browser where the user could select the folder?

Comment: There is no folder browser control in the CF, no.

Comment: its a shame ... i really dont like CF because of lacking so many basic stuff. Every other solution i need has a huge workaround thats painful to implement. Im already thinking about moving to Java (iphone, android) if the new SL for Windows Phone will have same issues.

Comment: This isn't a CF issue, it's a WinMo issue.  Use the same control under WinCE and it works fine.